# Why does Bower merge my main entries in bower.json?

Tags: gruntjs, bower

I've written a small jQuery plugin that pull into another project using Bower and install it with `grunt-bower-task`. The plugin's `bower.json` has two entries in `main` like this:

```
"main": [
    "src/jquery.myplugin.js",
    "src/jquery.myplugin.css"
],
```

However, the plugin won't install. I've been digging through `grunt-bower-task` adding `console.log`s here and there and I found out that the `bower.commands.list` concatenates the entries in `main` into one string separated by a comma(!).

I'm using bower v1.2.4, grunt-cli v0.4.1, grunt v0.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `grunt-bower-task` depends an older version of Bower which has this bug.